# Invalid XAML Exception in ItemTemplate with Telerik DataBoundListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik

I am attempting to use a Telerik RadDataBoundListBox with a custom ItemTemplate. However, when I attempt to set the DataTemplate I receive an Invalid XAML exception and can no longer compile. Should I be using Styles?

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox Grid.Row="1">
   <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

This error occurs no matter what is inside the DataTemplate tags.

Comment: What kind of XAML exception did you get?

Comment: Invalid XAML, I'll append that to the question

Comment: Try to re-add the Telerik references

Comment: Readding the references and restarting Visual Studio seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks!